# Does CouchDB getting cursor when requesting similar MongoDB?

Tags: couchdb

I need to transfer large amounts of data from CouchDB. The query returns all available keys, for which I am requesting documents. There is an option immediately obtain all documents. But size is only transmitted keys takes longer 1GB. In MongoDB is there for such tasks cursor, but it uses a different protocol.

How can I get at once all the documents contained in CouchDB, fingering them one by one?

I tried to touch the keys portions, but I consider this option in the last turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CouchDB Docs explain how to paginate results](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/views/pagination.html?highlight=view%20pagination)